# How to avoid the default data which spans several pages?

Tags: jhipster

I'm learning *JHipster*. There is no problem when I import my entities. But after launching the server and the front application, I see my entities on the default data which I cannot delete. The question is how to avoid the default data which spans across several pages?

Answer (score 1):

You can deactivate faker in src/main/resources/config/application-dev.yml:

```
 liquibase:
    # Remove 'faker' if you do not want the sample data to be loaded automatically
    contexts: dev, faker
```